# Javascript: dictionary/object membership check speed

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I was curious as of what would be the fastest way to check if a JS object (used as a dictionary) has a given property.

And I was baffled by the results. See for yourself: http://jsperf.com/object-membership-check-speed/6

In Chrome, the `in` keyword method is 96% slower than the dot syntax.
And in Firefox, it's also around 80% slower. IE shows about 50% slower

What the hell? Am I doing something wrong?
I imagined the "in" keyword would be optimized, since it doesn't even need to get the value, it just returns a boolean. But apparently I was plain wrong.

Comment: Not much difference for me in Firefox 4.0b6/Windows: array syntax is fastest, dot syntax 3% slower, 'in' keyword 10% slower.

Comment: For a laugh, try running this in IE8. You'll get tired of closing the "This script is running slowly. Do you want to end it?" dialogs. For the record, IE8 ran ~60 times slower than Chrome. :)

Comment: For the record, they all "get" the value, since they have to determine if such a value exists (so something *has* to be returned), and each way must access the specific member.

Comment: @Robusto Yeah forget about IE.. I also wonder if the test results are flawed for IE since the timer might not stop while the dialog is open.  But the `in` keyword is a bit different than the other methods, since it returns `true` even if the value of the key has been explicitly set to `undefined`. With the other methods I believe it's not even possible to check if something has been set explicitly or not

Comment: @Robusto - Regardless of whatever goes on internally, the `in` operator need not *return* the value of said property. Intuitively, `in` would seem the fastest as checking if a property has ever been defined would seem like a necessary first step in fetching its value, thus you'd think `in` would have less work to do than the alternatives. However, optimizations are rarely intuitive, and it might just be that the more common use case is the one that is more heavily optimized.

Comment: I think the tests would be more accurate to wrap each in an `if` statement, since then you're also testing the speed of converting the dot expression to a `bool`, which is something `in` has to do anyway.

Comment: @palswim good point, I updated the test. No noticeable difference however

Answer (score 7):

They are **not the same**.

- `obj.prop` will check if a property is **not falsy** (not `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `false`).
- `prop in obj` checks whether a property **exists** in an object (including it's prototype chain)
- And finally you have `obj.hasOwnProperty('prop')` which checks if the object has `prop` as it's **own property** (can't be an inhereted one).

*Example*

```
var obj = { prop: "" };
obj.prototype = { inhereted: true };
if ( obj.prop );            // false
if ( prop in object );      // true
if ( inhereted in object ); // true
if ( obj.hasOwnProperty('prop') );      // true
if ( obj.hasOwnProperty('inhereted') ); // false
```

I think performance shouldn't be a problem as long as you're not doing millions of checks at a time. If you really want the fastest way though, you can use:

```
if ( obj.prop != null )
```

Which checks if the property is not `null` or `undefined`. In this form other falsy values like `""` or `0` can't interfere, and you're still super performant.

Comment: I understand they're not the same. But it's still surprising to see that the simplest (in theory at least) method is the slowest. BTW- I added the hasOwnProperty method to the benchmark to see how it goes, and it's about the same speed of `in`.. a bit surprising as well since it involves getting a property `hasOwnProperty`, and calling that function. While as `in` is just a language construct.